# What is the difference between RGBAFormat and RGB5A1 for QOpenGLTexture?

Tags: qt, opengl-es

I know `RGBAFormat` is for ES 2 and `RGB5A1` is standard in ES 3, but, as I understand it, they both store data as RGB with 5 bits each and 1 bit for alpha.

I am trying to use a format that is common to both ES 2 and ES 3. On some devices, only one of the two work and neither works on all.

I am calling: `QOpenGLTexture::setData` with `QOpenGLTexture::RGBA` and `QOpenGLTexture::UInt16_RGB5A1`, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are confusing between types and untyped format.

RGBA with  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE  is same as RGBA8

RGBA with  GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1 is same as GL_RGB5_A1

How does this work?

In ES2 consider this call:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,texture->m_width,texture->m_height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,texture->m_data[0][0]);
```

In ES3 the same can be called in 2 different ways:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,texture->m_width,texture->m_height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL);
```

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,**GL_RGBA8**,texture->m_width,texture->m_height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL);

For your specific case, I think you should stick with GL_RGBA8 with GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE if you want to match the format between different versions.

Comment: those two lines for ES 3 are the same. My data is in RGB5A1 so I'd like to use that texture format, but QOpenGLTexture::RGB5A1 doesn't seem to work on some ES 2 devices, and in those cases QOpenGLTexture::RGBAFormat works. Is RGB5A1 not supported by both, or how am I using Qt's api incorrectly?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now. My point is in ES2 there is no concept of typed format.(typed - all those that specify the type+format in same enum).

Comment: I haven't used QT but from their documentation: QOpenGLTexture::RGBAFormat 0x1908 Equivalent to GL_RGBA (OpenGL ES 2 only)  is same as    QOpenGLTexture::RGBA8_UNorm 0x8058 Equivalent to GL_RGBA8.